# Android -Compress bitmap array of images

Tags: android, arrays, bitmap

I have a `Bitmap [] images`. But line

```
images.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
```

causes error

> Cannot invoke compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat, int,
>   ByteArrayOutputStream) on the array type Bitmap[]

In my search I got codes to compresss to one bitmap.but nothing to compress Bitmap array.

**code**

```
Bitmap[] images = {BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.candle1),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources   
(),R.drawable.candl3),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.senson),BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.lawn)}; 
ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 //  images.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
img=bos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: What do you expect to come out from compressing a bitmap array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compress the Bitmap array in a loop, like this:

```
byte[][] img = new byte[images.length][];

for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    images[i].compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);

    // use a 2D array for img if you want to retain the byte arrays for all the bitmaps
    img[i] = bos.toByteArray();
}
```

I hope this helps.